# Get values of DataFrame index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with an index column that uses pandas `TimeStamps`.

How can I get the values of the index as if it were a normal column (`df["index"]`)?

Comment: You can use `idx = df.index.to_list()` which gives the index values in a List.

Comment: my work around has been to durn the entire df into a dict in a format that preserves the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the index values from your dataframe by the following:

```
df.index.values
```

The above will return an array of the index values of your dataframe.
You can simply store that in a variable. You can also get the values as a list by the following:

```
list(df.index.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the index to a regular column by using the reset_index() method.

Comment: it works but I prefer the other answer